# Extract the variable importance using the `randomForest` package from a `cforest`

Tags: r, random-forest, party

Is it possible to extract the variable importance using the `randomForest` package from a `cforest` using the `partykit` package?

Here is some code, where I try to extract the variable importance of both a "normal" `randomforest` and a `cforest`:

```
# Load the required libraries
library(randomForest)
library(partykit)

# Set a random seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Generate synthetic data
n <- 100  # Number of data points
x1 <- rnorm(n)  # Predictor 1
x2 <- rnorm(n)  # Predictor 2
y <- ifelse(x1^2 + x2^2 > 1, 1, 0)  # Response variable

# Create a data frame
data <- data.frame(x1 = x1, x2 = x2, y = y)


# Fit a Random Forest model
rf_model <- randomForest(y ~ x1 + x2, data = data , ntree = 100)

# Fit a Conditional Inference Random Forest (cforest) model
cforest_model <- partykit::cforest(y ~ x1 + x2, data = data, ntree = 500)

# Varimp for randomforest
myvarimp1 <- randomForest::importance(rf_model) 

# Varimp for conditional randomforest
myvarimp2 <- randomForest::importance(cforest_model)
```

However when trying to use it on the cforest_model. I get this error:

> Error in UseMethod("importance") :
> no applicable method for 'importance' applied to an object of class "c('cforest', 'constparties', 'parties')"

Is it even possible to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to calculate the variable importance for the conditional random forest model.

```
myvarimp2 = varimp(cforest_model, conditional = T)

dotchart(sort(myvarimp2), main = "Conditional Importance of Variables")
```

The `varimp` function is available in `partykit` package for the variable importance calculation of conditional random forest model following the permutation principle of the ‘mean decrease in accuracy’ importance in ‘randomForest’.

Comment: Thanks. Since I want to use the same "kind" of variable importance, I'm using now `myvarimp2 = varimp(cforest_model, conditional = F)`.